# Do I need a transit visa for Don Mueang Airport(DMK), Bangkok

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dmk

I am an Indian citizen travelling from Chengdu, China to Mumbai, India on Thai Lion Air.

My itinerary is as follows:

- Flight SL933 - Chengdu(CTU) to Don Mueang(DMK) - Depart at 03:35 and arrive at 05:50 on November 1
- Flight SL218 - Don Mueang(DMK) to Mumbai(BOM) - Depart at 02:25 and arrive at 05:40 on November 2

I have a 20h35m layover at Bangkok's Don Mueang airport (DMK). Do I need a transit visa for Bangkok? The entire itinerary is on a single ticket.

Answer (score -3):

Update: The embassy website is not clear. You are recommended to call up airlines and clarify it.

You won't need a Transit visa.

Since, its not the primary Airport, the sleeping situations and facilities will be tight. But noone will prevent you from staying there for 20 hours and catch the next flight.

Reference - http://www.thaiembassy.org/telaviv/en/services/685/17388-Entry-to-Thailand.html

To be on the safe side, give a call to your Airline.

PS: There is Visa on Arrival for Indians. It costs 2000 THB (Roughly 4500) and you have to show enough funds (10k THB, ATM slip will do) to get out of Airport. I have covered Bangkok in a single day in such a transit.

Comment: Please add an explanation or a reference to why a visa is not required. [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=TH&TV=Thailand&h=87cae3ecf93fb35d3bac5e9225ed689965f642) does say that Indians need a visa for a layover of more than 12 hours at DMK.

Comment: http://www.thaiembassy.org/telaviv/en/services/685/17388-Entry-to-Thailand.html

Comment: Please [edit] your response to add this information. The link you have provided is for visa on arrival but the question is about need for a transit visa. Please elaborate the answer by providing relevant links as to why OP will be allowed Transit Without Visa for the given itinerary.

Comment: @RedBaron I couldn't find the 12 hour restriction any place. On the other hand, the embassy website doesn't specify any time limit.

Comment: It is true that Tel Aviv embassy page only mentions "short transit". Since you have provided an emphatic "No you don't need a transit visa", you should back up that assertion with verifiable links. Otherwise your answer risks being down-voted, especially because it contradicts the Timatic advice available on the net.